# How do i call the below function in C?

Tags: c, function, boolean-operations

> Returning `true` or `false`

```
bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z);

    int main(void)
    {
        float a = get_float("Enter the 1st Value : \n");
        float b = get_float("Enter the 2nd Value : \n");
        float c = get_float("Enter the 3rd Value : \n");
        return valid_triangle(a,b,c);
    }

    bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        if(x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
        if((x + y <= z) || (x + z <= y) || (z + y <= x))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to tell us what is the problem with the code you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
return valid_triangle(a,b,c);
```

to:

```
bool result = valid_triangle(a,b,c);
printf("%d\n", result);
```

Explanation: the C11 standard mentions these two valid signatures of `main` function:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

None of them doesn't return `bool`.